# Authentication in PHP session timeout

Tags: php, authentication

I am currently following this guide:
https://samjlevy.com/php-ldap-login/

It all works great and the login script works fine.
Only what I want to do is insert a simple piece of code that the session times out in like 30 minutes or something and than the user automaticly logs out.

How can I archieve this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
          session_start();
          $t=time();
          if (isset($_SESSION['logged']) && ($t - $_SESSION['logged'] >1800)) {
          session_destroy();
          session_unset();
          header('location: index.php');
          }else {$_SESSION['logged'] = time();}
```

Comment: I have put this in the login script and with 60 seconds instead of 1800 but it doesnt return after I login and wait for 60 seconds

Comment: Could you please share your login script if you don't mind